# Architecture required to build an authentication service

Tags: architecture

Currently building a website, which requires interaction between an app and the server side. see picture below.

I’d like to be able to register app usage for a specific user, and specific device.

Are there any good practice to achieve this?

Proposed architecture 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXrOQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are standards for this. One is called oauth2 https://oauth.net/2/.
That one is very powerful and might be too complicated depending on the use case. A simpler solution might be based on JWT token based authentication: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Authentication is easy to get wrong and that might lead to the loss of customer data. So I'd recommend to use a framework that supports your use case after truly understanding their documentation.